# How to prevent timeout response to winform client from WCF service

Tags: winforms, wcf, timeout

I have a WCF service method being called by a winform client.  The client passes a couple strings to the method, the method then performs a series of operations which can take in excess of 20 minutes.
At around 15 minutes into the process the client receives a response that the TCP connection has been terminated.  The WCF service continues to process beyond this point until it finishes the job.
I have set the timeouts in the binding configuration in the client to 30 minutes each.  I have also set the compilation batch timeout to 30 minutes.  The WCF service returns a string to the client just saying "Success", so it is not a size issues regarding the transmission.  It almost seems as if IIS is terminating the TCP connection due to some timeout.

An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.svc . This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. Inner Exception: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. Inner Exception: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. Inner Exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Any help?  The error is generated by the winform client, not the wcf service btw.

Here are the binding settings:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="WSHttpBinding_STUFFGOESHERE" closeTimeout="00:30:00"
   openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00"
   bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
   maxBufferPoolSize="524288000" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
   textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
   <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
   <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:30:00"
    enabled="false" />
   <security mode="Message">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
    realm="" />
   <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
    algorithmSuite="Default" />
  </security>
 </binding>
 </wsHttpBinding>
```

Comment: did you also updated the server configuration?

Comment: yes i added an httpRuntime maxRequestLength="30000000" executionTimeout="1800" on the web config.

Comment: I've also discovered that the client application calling the wcf service throws the error when the service has completed its operation and returns the message.

Comment: can you post your config? if you are using tcp probably you need to update your service endpoint bining

Comment: my config is broken up into multiple config sources, which parts are you most interested in, and which config, the client or service?

Comment: I can also tell you that when the service executes a smaller percentage lets say around 60% it returns correctly without any errors.  it's only on the higher processing content when it causes the application to throw an error.

Comment: Try to enable wcf tracing, use svcTraceViewer to review the logs

Comment: my problem with that is that I dont believe its in the service, as its the client throwing the error, the service itself throws no exceptions.  This has been verified as the case.

Comment: you can enable tracing on both of them, this will allow you to find who really throw an exception.

Comment: is there a firewall in between that is closing the connection?

Answer (score 0):

have you set the timeouts on your httpbinding?
in code:

```
((WSHttpBinding)binding).OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
((WSHttpBinding)binding).CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
((WSHttpBinding)binding).SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
((WSHttpBinding)binding).ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
```

or in the service config-file

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding openTimeout="00:1:00" 
             closeTimeout="00:1:00" 
             sendTimeout="00:30:00" 
             receiveTimeout="00:30:00">
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924831.aspx

Comment: yes as I mentioned in my original post I set all the timeout bindings available in the client config

Comment: I have now attempted both without success, to resolve issue I have made the long running service call have no return value thereby killing the tcp connection.